# JS not working as expected when selecting options from dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

**Goal**

1. clicking on a member of the `<ul>` selects/deselects it.
2. if class=allSearch is selected any other li's that are already selected are de-selected.
3. if allSearch is selected and then notAllSearch is selected, allSearch is deselected.

**Problem**

Goal 3 is not working, which doesn't make sense to me because it should be (and is) basically the same code used in Goal 2.

Here's the code:

HTML

```
<ul class="menu vertical" id="searchMenu">
    <li id="allSearch" class="allSearch selected">All</li>
    <li id="notAllSearch" class="notAllSearch">User</li>
    <li id="notAllSearch" class="notAllSearch">Artists</li>
    <li id="notAllSearch" class="notAllSearch">Events</li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#searchMenu li').click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
        }
    else if ($(this).hasClass('notAllSearch')) {
        $('#allSearch').removeClass('selected')
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
    else if ($(this).hasClass('allSearch')) {
        $('#notAllSearch').removeClass('selected')
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
    else
        $(this).addClass('selected');
});
})
```

Comment: The problem could be the fact that you have used the same ID for 3 elements (notAllSearch)

Comment: @Lakutis oh yea? I wasn't aware that could cause issues.  This is gona seem like a stupid question, but whats the equivalent of ".hasClass" for ID?

Comment: ID name should be unique for whole html page. It is html-specification. You can use $('#notAllSearch') but in html structure should be only one element with id='notAllSearch'. Otherwise you should use classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : instead of ID work on CLASS for this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#searchMenu li').click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
    }
    else if ($(this).hasClass('notAllSearch')) {
        $('.allSearch').removeClass('selected')
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
    else if ($(this).hasClass('allSearch')) {
        $('.notAllSearch').removeClass('selected')
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        }
    else
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
});
```

Here is the [pen to test](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JGeyxR)

Comment: That did it, thanks!! So was my problem simply overusing ID's? Aside from it being bad practice, do you know what actually stopped it from working?

Comment: When you were using ID's for last 3 `li's` it will just impact upon the first occurring of respective ID in the DOM and rest will be neglected. That was causing the error.